# How to open a PostgreSQL database dump in R

Tags: r, postgresql

i have many files (with no extension) that i would like to open  with R and extract data.frames.

it says in the header that it is a

### --
m -- PostgreSQL database dump

It has many tables inside it, and the only noticeable pattern i detected is that and the end of each table it has a "."  (see print screen)

is there a smart way to import this file and and extract/break it into meaningful dataframes?

Thank you in advance!

[image: header clip]

[image: table example]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: A dump needs to be "imported" into a running PostgreSQL server. As this is a "plain text" dump, you simply run that SQL script using `psql`